# efficiently creating a panel data.frame from cross sections with unharmonized column names

Tags: r

I need to create a panel data set (long format) from multiple yearly (cross-sectional) data sets. The variables of interest have different names in the single data sets and i need to harmonize them.

I loaded the dataframes to a list and now want to manipulate the names using `lapply` or a chunk of code that allows binding the dataframes. I can see several ways of doing this, but would like to use one which works with little code on a large list of data.frames, so that I can do this for several variables and easily change specifics later on.

So what I am looking for is either a way to rename the columns, so that I able to simple use `bind_rows()` from dplyr or an equivalent method, or a way to rename and bind the datasets in one step. Since I need to do this for several variables it might be safer to keep the two steps apart.

To illustrate, here an example:

```
a <- data.frame(id=c("Marc", "Julia", "Rico"), year=2000:2002, laborincome=1:3)
b <- data.frame(id=c("Marc", "Julia", "Rico"), earningsfromlabor=2:4, year=2003:2005)
dflist <- list(a, b)

equivalent_vars <- c("laborincome", "earningsfromlabor")
newnanme <- "income"
```

Desired result:

data.frame(id=c("Marc", "Julia", "Rico"), income=c(1,2,3,2,3,4), year=2000:2005)

```
     id income year
1  Marc      1 2000
2 Julia      2 2001
3  Rico      3 2002
4  Marc      2 2003
5 Julia      3 2004
6  Rico      4 2005
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `setnames` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
do.call(rbind, Map(setnames, dflist, old = equivalent_vars, new = newnanme))
#     id year income
#1  Marc 2000      1
#2 Julia 2001      2
#3  Rico 2002      3
#4  Marc 2003      2
#5 Julia 2004      3
#6  Rico 2005      4
```

---

Or we can use the `:=`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map2_df(dflist, equivalent_vars, ~ .x %>%
                 rename(!! (newnanme) := !! .y)) %>%
       select(id, income, year)
#     id income year
#1  Marc      1 2000
#2 Julia      2 2001
#3  Rico      3 2002
#4  Marc      2 2003
#5 Julia      3 2004
#6  Rico      4 2005
```

Comment: thank you, the problem is that the relevant variable is not always at the second position. its a very messy data set

Comment: I tried all the solutions and they work perfectly, I think I prefer the `do.call` in this case and also found out that using `map2` instead of `map2_df` creates a list of df's, which might be usefull since I need to harmonize severall variables step by step.

Comment: @yoland yes, `map2/map` etc. returns a list.  One option is that while you are doing the transformations step by step, use `map2` and in the last step after checking the output, change it to `map2_df`